# php file_get_contents function saves invalid image file in my new webserver

Tags: image, webserver, file-get-contents, corrupt

I have developed a wordpress plugin which uses `file_get_contents()` to retrieve images from distant url and save it in the local folder using fwrite function.  The image file gets saved in a local folder so it can be referenced later.

This works fine in one webserver 1. But when I installed the plugin in wordpress maintained in a different new webserver 2, the file gets created in the local folder but seems it gets corrupted. The file is created properly for images which are less than 100kb i guess, but larger files which are properly created in the former webserver 1 are corrupted when retrieved and created in server 2.

Below is the code I use to retrieve images and save to local folder:

```
//$imgurl = url of the image file and $upload_path 
// is path where image will be stored

$file = file_get_contents($imgurl) or die('File too large or inacessible');
$myFile = $upload_path . "\internal\folder\structure\\" . $file_name;
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Error");
$fwrite = fwrite($fh, $file);

if($fwrite === false)
{
    echo "error";
}
else
{
    echo "file has been created ".$file_name;
}

fclose($fh);
```

In server 1 this works fine, but in server 2, the file gets created but cant open it because it is corrupted. I guess this probably should have to do with the php configuration of the server 2 but I am not very sure so I am looking forward for your help.

Comment: check if something is outputting before this functionality on the server2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several reasons

1. PHP Error generated by something on server2
2. some output like newline or space before your function

read http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for hint